# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions in UISplitViewController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift2, ios9, uisplitviewcontroller

My `UISplitViewController` basically works like a charm except that there is an annoying error message displayed when transitioning the first time (first time only!) from the master table view to the detail view.

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0x160015600>.
```

Both the master and the detail view controller are embedded in a `UINavigationController`. However, the error only occurs when setting the following (which is necessary for logic behavior on the iPhone):

```
class MySplitViewController: UISplitViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

It would be great if anyone could provide a solution to this issue, thanks in advance.

BTW: the split view controller was set up in the storyboard

Presenting the detail view controller is done in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method like this:

```
if let detailViewController = delegate as? DetailViewController {
    detailViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
    detailViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController!.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController!.showDetailViewController(detailViewController.navigationController!, sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Facing the same issue while building everything programatically as well. So I suppose whether it is done on storyboard or programatically, this issue occurs.

Comment: Refer - http://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/MathMonsters-Swift-Final.zip and then add the `func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool { return true }`

Comment: Try it on the iPhone

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, your first transition from master (`UITableView` in `UIViewController`?) to detail (`UIViewController`) view in your `UISplitViewController` starts before the active/current view has finished displaying itself.

A possible reason for this is that you are possibly trying to present the first "instance" of the detail view in the `viewDidLoad()` method of you master `UIViewController`? In such a case, you app might try to present the detail view *prior to master view finished appearing*. Note the difference here between *view did load* a view and *view did appear*:

> *override func viewDidLoad()*
>
> **Description:**
>
> Called after the controller's view is loaded into memory.
>
> This method is called after the view controller has *loaded its view
>   hierarchy into memory*.
>
> ---
>
> *override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)*
>
> **Description:**
>
> Notifies the view controller that its *view was added to a view
>   hierarchy*. You can override this method to perform additional tasks
>   associated with presenting the view.

Now, as you question doesn't show how you load your initial detail view, the following advice is maybe already heeded by yourself, but anyway: if your detail view is presented from the `viewDidLoad()`, try to move this to the `viewDidAppear()` method:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    // present/load detail view here instead
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying when I present the detail view controller, check out the edited question. Still, thanks for your effort, that's what I had read before asking this question as well, however I can't think of a way my application is doing this.

Comment: @OliverBorchert Hmm, then without a more detailed view of your code, I don't really know. Do you possible animate some transition at some point in the first state change to detail? (`animation: ...`). If so, possibly set such animations to `false` for testing if they are the reason for your error (i.e., causing overlaying transitions)

Comment: I really only have the split view controller in my application :/

Comment: I suspect `self.delegate = self` is the source of the error. Usually you set some type instance *within* your class as the delegate (i.e. `var textField = UITextField` has a delegate defined as `textField.delegate = self`). Using `self.delegate = self` might create a loop behaviour for callbacks, which e.g. overlay two views instantaneously (in so animating two transitions at once).

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late an answer, but anyways, I solved this using perform segue instead of showDetailViewController

Comment: `showDetailViewController` has some special purpose in a `UISplitViewController` it pushes / presents depending on the size classes (adaptive). So it is better to use `showDetailViewController`, but this seems to be a problem